# Sending log analytics workspace logs to Sentinel

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, azure-sentinel

I am managing two distinct resource groups under the same Azure subscription. The first resource group is equipped with Azure Sentinel, while the second hosts a Log Analytics workspace dedicated to aggregating GitLab logs. My goal is to configure the Log Analytics workspace to forward its data to the resource group containing Azure Sentinel.

Could anyone guide me on how to achieve this integration?

Comment: Have you tried any approach so far? If yes, could you share it here? @MatrhWonder00

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to configure a data connector to link the Log Analytics workspace with Sentinel.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sentinel/connect-data-sources#enable-a-data-connector

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sentinel/quickstart-onboard

Have you tried it?